# embeddable internationalization frameworks within my java web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, localization, internationalization

Can you suggest me any opensource localization and internationalization frameworks that can be embedded in my java web application? as i dont want to reinvent the wheel.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try Cosmopolitan (c10n): http://rodionmoiseev.github.com/c10n/

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful for you http://l10n.ws it works for me